# How do I create a block?

Tags: blocks

I am trying to create a block using hook_block, in Drupal 7. I have the following code in my module file (module.module its not actually called that but, this is an example).

```
function module_race_results_block_info($op = 'list'){
  $block = array();

  if ($op == 'list') {
    $block[0]['info'] = t('Race Results Block');
  }

  return $block;
}

function module_race_results_block_view($delta = 'raceresults') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'raceresults':
      $block['content'] = module_race_results();
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

function module_race_results() {
  $content = "Testing Race Results Block";

  return $content;
}
```

How can I test this? The block is not showing up in the blocks list (/admin/structure/block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly, it's `$block['content']=module_race_results();` in your `hook_block_view()`, and `$blocks['raceresults']...` in your `hook_block_info()` so it matches your `hook_block_view()`.

More precisely, this is probably more of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
function module_race_results_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['raceresults']['info'] = t('Race Results Block');
  // any more blocks here

  return $blocks;

}


function module_race_results_block_view($delta) {
  $blocks = array();

  switch($delta) {
    case 'raceresults':
      $blocks['subject'] = t('Race Results');
      $blocks['content'] = module_race_results();
      break;

    // any more blocks here

    }
  }

  return $blocks;
}

function module_race_results() {
  $content = "Testing Race Results Block";  // eventually this should become a renderable array instead of plain text or html
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: for what its worth, your code as-is shows up on the block list when I run it (refer to Jima for how it should work). I thought a simple reminder to provide a .info file, and enable the module on admin/modules would help. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for fixing up the code. but its still not showing up in the /admin/structure/block page.

Comment: and your module is installed/enabled per @gamengineers comment above?

Comment: (note that given your hooks were somewhat invalid earlier, you may need to disable/re-enable the module for drupal's caches to get back in sync)

Comment: Yes, the module is enabled. Also, I have cleared the cache and reinstalled.

Comment: One of us must have an 'off by one' error someplace then.  Initially you declared $blocks but returned $block.  Just make sure you don't have a subtle typo like that someplace.  YOURMODULE must match everywhere for the hook to be found etc.

Comment: I checked the code again and everything seems fine. Are there any other files I should have? I only have a .module and a .info file.

Comment: just that WHATEVER.info (and/or name = inside) needs to match WHATEVER.module and WHATEVER_block_view().

Comment: also, _'s get into trouble sometimes in module names because you take over multiple namespaces, e.g. module foo_bar will "own" foo's and foo_bar's namespaces, so, make sure you don't have another module that could be colliding with this one

Comment: Okay, it finally showed up. I had the ending php tag in the file. Thanks for your help!